# EC2 config change on BItnami Wordpress?

Tags: bitnami

I am deploying Wordpress site using Bitnami AMI on EBS-backed EC2. Wordpress database will be stored in EBS.

Does Bitnami provides with updated config like Amazon does for better performance & security.

EBS Snapshot is not of any help as new EC2 already has a EBS attached.

Do I have to always migrate my Wordpress site using backup & do this upgradtion?

Answer (score 0):

> Does Bitnami provides with updated config like Amazon does for better performance & security.

Bitnami offers a ready for production solution on AWS for WordPress called WordPress Multi Tier. You can learn more about this solution reading the docs in the links below:

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws-templates/get-started/

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws-templates/apps/wordpress/

> Do I have to always migrate my Wordpress site using backup & do this upgradtion?

You can migrate your Site following the instructions detailed in the Bitnami Documentation:

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/migrate-wordpress/